# FFmpeg returns' Output must be specified' when it has been acknowledged

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Here's my command in python:

```
ffmpeg -i concat:803.ts|804.ts|805.ts -c copy output.ts
```

When I run the command it opens the output but it doesn't save the file to the directory.
I run the command in FFmpeg and it gave the same result - it opened the output but it gave me this error at the end:

```
At least one output file must be specified
```

I don't understand what I did wrong as I specified the output clearly, I already checked for solutions but most of them are suited to OP's needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to quote the entire input string.

```
-i "concat:803.ts|804.ts|805.ts"
```

else the shell will think the first pipe character is redirecting ffmpeg's output to `804.ts`. Since ffmpeg sees only `-i concat:803.ts`, it complains about missing output file.

Comment: how about when I'm merging aac files together?

Comment: The input type doesn't matter.